# Android textview not scaled

Tags: android, textview, scale

I have a problem with the layout. My textview contains text, which is a little bit too much to see on the screen. The text I can't see at my device is cutted. How can I set that the textview scale, that I can see the whole text?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >



                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/l1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/crunch1" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/button2links"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/links2" />


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/crunch2" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/button2rechts"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"                            
                            android:src="@drawable/rechts2" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Crunch"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/crunch" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/pause"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:onClick="verlaufKlick"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is only at TextView: android:id="@+id/textView1"

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height of that TextView as 0dp.If you are setting height as 0dp then you need to set weight, or else make the height as wrap content.

Comment: I set wrap_content instead of android:layout_height="0dp", but the text is cutted, too.

Comment: If you want to set the text in center set gravity and not scaletype for textview

Comment: No, I want that I can see all of my text, in the second snapshot there is text missing.

Answer (score 0):

The text is cropped horizontally or vertical?

scaleType works for `ImageView` not `TextView`. on a `TextView` you can use `scaleX` and `scaleY`.
But you should set different text sizes depending on the screen size

Comment: In the xml. you set the textSize using a dimension. and you can have different dimensions depending on the screen size (by placing them in different values folders)

Comment: adjustViewBounds is also an ImageView attribute